# Generalizing a well known formula for adding first $n$ numbers

Tags: summation

We know

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{ n (n+1) }{2} $$

How about if

$$ \sum_{k=j}^n k $$

I know that we there are $n-j$ numbers, thus

$$ \sum_{k=j}^n k = \frac{ (n -j)( n-j+1) }{2} $$

However, by book states that

$$ \sum_{k=j}^n k = \frac{ (n +j)( n-j+1) }{2} $$

instead. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If $n=j$, then we get $\sum_{k=j}^nk=n$, but according to your first formula, this is clearly wrong.  Also note that in order for us to tell you what you are doing wrong, we need to know what you did.  So, what did you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking of $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-j}k=\frac{(n-j)(n-j+1)}{2}$$
But clearly $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-j}k\neq\sum\limits_{k=j}^{n}k$ so instead try this $$\sum_{k=j}^nk=\sum_{k=1}^nk-\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}k$$ 
From this it shouldn't be hard to derive the expression you want.